# How to Change Default Text Editor Annotation Preferences in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

So my Eclipse always uses a very weird text annotation (i.e. it highlights the errors instead of underlining them). I know how to change this.

```
Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations
```

But I can't save my settings; every time I reopen eclipse to that work space, all my saved annotation settings are gone. So it's very annoying change them every time. Is there a way I can change the default annotation settings?

Thanks!

Comment: It does persist it for me. What version of Eclipse are you using, and what language are you editing? If it's not storing between sessions then either something is resetting it on you during startup, or the editor for your particular language might have a bug.  I tried with Java and it was fine.

Comment: Maybe the settings files are sitting somewhere, where eclipse does not have write permissions? (Like C:\Program Files under Windows)

Comment: @stvcisco I'm using Luna(4.4 I believe?) and editing Java(JSE 1.8 if that helps) using the Eclipse dark theme.

Comment: @Soana I believe my Eclipse has permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be specific to when you're using a custom theme like `Dark` (does not happen with the `default` theme).  I am able to reproduce it with `Luna` also, but it seems to be fixed in the `Mars` version (4.5) which is due to release on Wednesday (June 24, 2015).  You can try one of the recent [release candidate builds](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php) if you can't wait until Wednesday.

[This bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435512) may be related to the changes that fixed it.  I also think the dark theme looks better in `Mars` with expansion tabs looking cleaner in the package explorer.